# Passar variável angularjs atraves de função JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, angularjs, funções

Tenho um modal dinâmico em Jquery que é chamado com o `onclick="ShowModal()"`  está funcionando. Porém, quero enviar valores vindo AngularJS e não consigo. Ele envia o código AngularJS `{{dado.idUser}}`, mas não o valor `01`.

`onclick="ShowModal('<?php echo URL.'Usuarios/?form=AlterarSenha&idu={{dado.idUser}}&nomeFunc={{dado.nomeFunc}}'; ?>',300,430)"`

fiz um teste, coloquei somente `onclick="ShowModal({{dado.idUser}})"` e fui exibir o código fonte para ver o resultado e ele não coloca o valor, só o código.

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso. Não entendo muito de Angular nem de JavaScript.

Comment: use a diretiva ng-click acredito que vá funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Você pode chamar uma *function* e pegar o valor usando `angular.element`:

**HTML**

```
onclick="exibirModal()"
```

**JS**

```
function exibirModal(){
    var nome = angular.element('#idMeuController').scope().dado.nomeFunc;
    ShowModal(nome);
}
```

Onde *idMeuController* é o *id* do elemento que possui o seu controle.

Comment: Vou estudar essa opção, mas a principio eu teria que fazer uma função para cada modal diferente, de acordo com as variáveis que eu quisesse passar. Eu acho.